# Appending elements to dom returns [object Object] or wrong data from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to append some li elements inside a ul. In this scenario, I am looping through the array called blogData and accessing each tags method. The issue I am having- I can't seem to loop through each array inside tags and appending data to the ul inside each article appends all tags data from each object to each ul.

```js
const blogData = [
    {
        title : "blog first",
        date : "01",
        tags : ["first", "second"],
        body : "Some text",
        id : 1
    },
    {
        title : "blog second",
        date : "02",
        tags :  ["third", "fourth"],
        body : "Some more text",
        id : 2
    }
];

function tagUl (object) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const ul = $('.tags-ul');
        for (let i = 0; i < ul.length; i++) {
            const $li = $('<li>');
            $li.text(object[i].tags);
            ul.append($li);            }
    }, 10);
}
tagUl(blogData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <ul class="tags-ul">
  </ul>
</article>

<article>
  <ul class="tags-ul">
  </ul>
</article>
```

As you can see here by running the code all ul tags get the same li's appended to them. As the title says it returns [object Object]. This was the case a few minutes ago when I was first writing this. The case now is that it simply returns the wrong data

Comment: Can you please post the desired output?

Comment: The desired output would go something like this: article one tags -> first second article two tags -> third fourth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `ul` variables represents *all* the `<ul class="tags-ul">` elements, and so doing an "append" on that variable appends the same content to all the elements it represents.

You can access each element separately, either by looping, or more crudely (since you already have a for loop to go through your blogData object), by getting the raw element from the jQuery object by its index, and then appending specifically to that. It also creates a separate `<li>` for each tag by looping through the tags array itself.

```js
const blogData = [{
    title: "blog first",
    date: "01",
    tags: ["first", "second"],
    body: "Some text",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    title: "blog second",
    date: "02",
    tags: ["third", "fourth"],
    body: "Some more text",
    id: 2
  }
];

function tagUl(object) {
  const ul = $('.tags-ul');
  for (let i = 0; i < ul.length; i++) {
    const $li = $('<li>');
    for (var j = 0; j < object[i].tags.length; j++) {
      $(ul[i]).append($("<li/>", { text: object[i].tags[j] }));
    }
  }
}

$(function() {
  tagUl(blogData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <ul class="tags-ul">
  </ul>
</article>

<article>
  <ul class="tags-ul">
  </ul>
</article>
```

P.S. I assumed your setTimeout was a kludge to allow the HTML content to load before you run the code, so I replaced it with a more reliable jQuery wrapper which waits for the document to be ready before executing any code within it (`$(function() { ... });` is a shorthand for the slightly more comprehensible statement `$(document).ready(function() ... });`)

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much. See when I was appending my elements to the ul I had [i] placed outside the jquery selector not inside. Very good. Thanks!

Comment: @Miles no problem, if it helped you please remember to upvote and/or mark as the accepted answer - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

you need to iterate tags array inside each object in blogData and then add `li` for each value inside the array. something like this will work:

```js
const blogData = [
    {
        title : "blog first",
        date : "01",
        tags : ["first", "second"],
        body : "Some text",
        id : 1
    },
    {
        title : "blog second",
        date : "02",
        tags :  ["third", "fourth"],
        body : "Some more text",
        id : 2
    }
];

function tagUl (object) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const ul = $('.tags-ul');
        for (let i = 0; i < ul.length; i++) {
            var tags = object[i].tags;
            for (var j=0; j<tags.length; j++){
               $(ul[i]).append("<li>" + tags[j] + "</li>");            
            }
        }
    }, 10);
}
tagUl(blogData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <ul class="tags-ul">
  </ul>
</article>

<article>
  <ul class="tags-ul">
  </ul>
</article>
```